# MongoDb Sharding on Local Machine

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to create a sharding on my local machine. But when I create MongoDB shard server in the bin directory using this command `start mongod --shardsvr --port 2005 -logpath C:\data\shard\s0\log\s0.log --dbpath C:\data\shard\s0` nothing happens so I went on to create mongos router `mongos --port 2007 --configdb test/localhost:2001`. Mongos created successfully and then I add shard to mongos using command `sh.addShard("localhost:2005")` then this error appears `"errmsg" : "failed to run command { isMaster: 1 } when attempting to add shard localhost:2005 :: caused by :: HostUnreachable: Error connecting to localhost:2005 (127.0.0.1:2005) :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."`. I don't know how to deal with this error.

Comment: For a sharded cluster you need at least 3 mongo server processes, the shard, the config and the mongos, maybe see [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) or use my scripts at https://github.com/Wernfried/mongoDB-oneclick

Comment: Please check this link   https://sanaulla.info/2015/02/02/setting-up-sharded-mongodb-cluster-in-localhost/